# How to load data by submitting value in React app

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

In my react and spring-boot application, I have 3 drop-down menus and a submit button. Once button click, it takes the value from the drop-down and sends the request to the controller and fetch DB values and finally display on a different page.

I tried following, but it was not successful. How to solve this issue?

```
return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="persent-one">
        <i className="fa fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <select className="textboxstyle" onChange={this.changeBrandLOV}><option value='-1'>Select Brand</option><option value ='0'>ALL</option>{optionItems}</select>
     </div>

     <div className="persent-one">
        <i className="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <select className="textboxstyle" onChange={this.changeFamilyLOV}><option value='-1'>Select Family</option><option value ='0'>ALL</option>{familyOptionItems}</select>
     </div>
     <div className="persent-one">
        <i className="fa fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <select className="textboxstyle"><option key='-1'>Select Model</option><option key='0'>ALL</option>{modelOptionItems}</select>
     </div>
     <div className="persent-one less-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" className="btn btn-info cst-btn" id="srch"/>
     </div>
  </div>
```

function

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                const searchRequest = Object.assign({}, values);
                searchModes(searchRequest,0,50)
                .then(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.accessToken);
                }).catch(error => {
                    if(error.status === 401) {
                        notification.error({
                            message: 'Polling App',
                            description: 'Your search selections are incorrect. Please try again!'
                        });
                    } else {
                        notification.error({
                            message: 'Polling App',
                            description: error.message || 'Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again!'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

function

```
export function searchModes(searchRequest,page, size) {
  page = page || 0;
  size = size || POLL_LIST_SIZE;

  return request({
      url: API_BASE_URL + "/models?page=" + page + "&size=" + size,
      method: 'GET'
  });
}
```

In Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/models")
public class ModelController {


    @GetMapping
    public PagedResponse<Model> getModels(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER) int page,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) int size) {

        return modelService.getAllModels(currentUser, page, size);
    }
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Do you know where it is failing? Does it manage to send the request? Is it just failing to display the results? Any log outputs from the web browser or client?

Comment: yes, it gives error here. 256 | 
  257 | handleSubmit(event) {
  258 |       event.preventDefault();
> 259 |       this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
  260 |           if (!err) {
  261 |               const searchRequest = Object.assign({}, values);
  262 |               searchModes(0,50)

Comment: That error isn't making a lot of sense to me. Are you sure that's the full & correct output? Add it to your question if it helps with formatting.

Comment: Hi @CameronDowner, I added the error page that displayed when clicking the button

Comment: The error you're getting isn't to do with the request. You are trying to call `this.props.form.validateFields` but `this.props.form` doesn't exist. You need to look into where you expect the `form` prop to come from.I think this question is too broad and I'm going to vote to close, but ask another question if you have a more specific issue